# Rotate slopes of a plane around the Z axis in 3-dimensional space

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d, rotations, transformation

I have a rectangular plane in 3D space, whose slope (height / length) along the X axis is say 0.3 and along the Y axis say 0.1. Now I rotate the plane around the Z axis by say 45°. How do I get the new slopes along X and Y axes respectively ? I've tried multiplying the slopes with sin(45) and / or cos(45), but both gave completely different results than I get by recreating that plane in a 3D design application (Blender), rotating it by 45° and calculating the slope from the vertex (point) positions.

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of a 3D rendering of the grid explained [in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138445/discussion-between-andrew-d-hwang-and-programmer), on the left with both max-slope and max-bank = 0, at the right with both = 1 (raw terrain elevations without clamping). The problem is that for max-slope = 1 and max-bank = 0, applying the formula in the answer below, I get new max-slope = 0.328899 and max-bank = 0.944365, which results in no clamping at all in this example, and would result in insufficient clamping for steeper terrain.

[image: Example image with unclamped "raw" terrain on the right and terrain clamped to 0% slope and bank on the left]

If needed I can add more screenshots from different angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we represent positions (points) and displacements (vectors) by $3 \times 1$ columns of numbers, then rotating through angle $\theta$ about the $z$-axis is accomplished by multiplying on the left by the rotation matrix
$$
R_{\theta} = \left[
  \begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
    \cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 \\
    \sin\theta & \phantom{-}\cos\theta & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}
  \right].
$$
If the plane has normal vector $n = (A, B, C)$, the rotated plane has normal vector
$$
R_{\theta} n = \left[
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    A\cos\theta - B\sin\theta \\
    A\sin\theta + B\cos\theta \\
    C
  \end{array}
  \right].
$$

Comment: Sounds good, but I don't have the normal, just the slope - does it work the same with that ?

Comment: Well, it does not work ! :(

Comment: As I understand the term slope with regard to planes, your plane has equation of the form $0.3x + 0.1y = z + D$, or $0.3x + 0.1y - z = D$, for $D$ the height of the plane where it crosses the $z$-axis. If so, we may choose $(A, B, C) = (0.3, 0.1, -1)$ as normal vector. Please post if that doesn't help.

Comment: Well, it does work … I guess I'm just using the results wrong, but that's off-topic. Your answer already helped a lot, thanks !

Comment: What should happen is, if $(A', B', C')$ are the rotated components, then the rotated plane has equation $A'x + B'y + C'z = D$ (the same $D$ as before). If there's something not working as expected, we can move this to chat....

Comment: Yes, please move to chat - I apparently don't have enough reputation to do it !

Comment: and I'm still having problems applying the fomula.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138445/discussion-between-andrew-d-hwang-and-programmer).